# Dynamic height animation with CSS hide and show children

Tags: jquery, css

I have a tabbed menu in which tabs have different heights.

I want to use CSS to animate the parent tab container when tabs are switched, I tried applying transition:all but it's not working. Is it possible?

This is the demo: http://jsbin.com/koyasu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Transition will work on element (and not to child elements), only if you set values before and after transition [check this](http://jsbin.com/pocasicadu/1/edit?html,css,js,output) .

Comment: I suggest you check [this Plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Easy-Animated-jQuery-Tabbed-Content-Plugin-Tabulous.html). It does what it should: when you switch the tab it calculates new content height and set it to parent (you can do it too).